# How do you prioritize SQL column values based on what is being insert?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am create a feature request web application where I am using sql to handle the feature request. 
This is how my table looks.

[image]

I have "id, title, description, client, clientPriority, date, and etc..

So lets say "Client 1" requests for some feature and sets the clientPriority to "1". Then they come back next day and requests for another feature and want to set the priority "1". So the first feature, which was requested with priory "1" should be pushed down to "2". Is it possible to accomplish this with sql? If so, how can I accomplish this with sql table?

**I am using Python sqlAlchemy.**

Comment: It is possible to handle it by sql, yes - using triggers, but it should NOT be handled by the database. It should be handled by the program, that uses the database

Comment: You need to perform an update on priority, or do you need to display it below the top priority row?

Comment: Thank you for comments @j.kaspar Guys. I need to push the priorities down based on if it exists!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have to run 2 queries in one transaction.

First it to move priorities `@priority` is what you going to insert (could be 1 or anything). Following assumes you want to move full stack. Which will make sense. Modify to "=" if you want to move one.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE tableName 
SET ClientPriority = ClientPriority + 1 
WHERE ClientPriority >= @priority

INSERT INTO tableName (feature, priority) 
VALUES @feature, @priority

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

In Alchemy it's same only fluent
Session = transaction so once you open it you good. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html

```
tablename.update().where(ClientPriority>=@priority).   values(ClientPriority=ClientPriority+1)
tablename.insert.values(feature=@feature, ClientPriority=@priority)
```

Adding the trigger as final solution from Neel Patel comment:

```
@event.listens_for(RequestedFeatures, 'before_insert') def receive_before_insert(mapper, connection, target): query = "UPDATE features SET clientPriority = (clientPriority + 1) WHERE client = '" query += target.client + "' AND clientPriority >= " + str(target.clientPriority) qr = session.execute(query) session.commit()
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Would you happen to know how to do it in SQLAlchemy using Python?

Comment: Session in SQLAlchemy is a transaction so once you open it you good. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html
as far as query
tablename.update().where(ClientPriority>=@priority).   values(ClientPriority=@priority)
tablename.insert.values(feature=@feature, ClientPriority=@priority)

Comment: Will this take care of changes in priority. So lets say if there is already something with priority "1" and other feature request is with priority "1" will it push the previous priority to "2"?

Comment: Sorry pasted wrong. Corrected alchemy portion. Yes it will it will increment existing starting from the priority level you inserting.